# Git and jMeter scripts

Tags: git, version-control, jmeter, project-structure

I have few jmeter scripts with me in my local. I have to keep them in my main Project in git so that I can integrate it to Jenkins.
Wanted to know how should be the project structure in Git.
So is it like:

```
Main Project Folder
    Module1
        TestPlan 1
        TestPlan 2
    Module 2
        TestPlan1
        TestPlan2
```

TestPlan1, TestPlan2 etc are the .jmx files which are the test scripts having multiple test cases?

Also, when we execute them through Jenkins, then we configure the main Project folder in Jenkins, will it pick all the scripts under it for execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins doesn't do any magic, it basically checks out [configured Git repository](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) and executes build steps (most likely you will run JMeter using [command-line non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui))

So given the same command you use to run your JMeter test locally works - it should work in Jenkins as well. Just remember [not to use full paths](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/4-things-you-should-never-do-your-jmeter-script) to modules, CSV files, etc.

Comment: What Dmitri said.  Also you may need to use something like this so Jenkins interprets jmeter results correctly:  https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin

Comment: Thanks for answering but let me reframe my question- My project has suppose 5 modules. Then the Performance Project Structure should be like?
Main Project Folder
    Module1
        TestPlan 1 - .jmx file
        TestPlan 2 - .jmx file
    Module 2
        TestPlan1
        TestPlan2
Like the structure mentioned in the above question